# How to get dates between time range in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a stored procedure in which i will get begin date and end date. for eg: start date is 05/07/2015 and end date is 28/08/2015. I need to write a query which will fetch details between 01/07/2015 and 31/08/2015. It should fetch details between 1st day of month selected for begin date and last day of month selected for end date.

This is what I tried, but it isn't working:

```
DATEDIFF(month,'2014-06-05','2014-08-05')
```

Comment: If the end date is the 28th, why would you filter based on the 31st?

Comment: DATEDIFF returns an int for the number of intervals crossed by two dates. This would tell you how many months passed between those two dates. You need to use > and < for this. Where YourDateColumn > '2015-07-01' and YourDateColumn < '2015-08-31'. You could use BETWEEN but there some challenges with that. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: You want to do this with a stored procedure?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=date+functions+in+sql+serve&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=date+functions+in+sql+serve&gs_l=hp....0.0.1.4476892...........0.D9F4HHB9dek#q=get+first+day+of+month+in+sql+server

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the dates using the common operators "<" and ">", 
Example:

```
select * from table_name where '2014-06-05' < datefield and  datefield  < '2014-08-05'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME

DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = convert(DATE, '20140705' ,112)

SET @EndDate = convert(DATE, '20140828' ,112)

SELECT * FROM [TableName] WHERE [TableName].DateField BETWEEN 
    dateadd(d,-(datepart(d, @StartDate)-1),@StartDate) AND 
    dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1, dateadd(d,-(datepart(d, @EndDate)-1),@EndDate)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to find the first day of the month for '05/07/2015' and the last day of the month for '28/08/2015', then use those as the limits for your where clause.

This will easily convert a date to the first of the month:

```
declare @firstDate datetime = '2015-07-05'
declare @firstOfMonth datetime = dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@firstDate),0)
select @firstDate
-- returns '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000'
```

To get to the last day of a month, use this:

```
declare @lastDate datetime = '2015-08-28'
declare @lastOfMonth datetime = dateadd(second,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@lastDate)+1,0))
select @lastOfMonth
-- returns '2015-08-31 23:59:59.000'
```